# Disableling logon screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How can I completely disable the logon screen on windows 7 like in Windows 95 there is no such screen?

I mean that no sky blue screen at all. Is there any way?

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: I have several W7 pc's that do not show login screens, when I installed W7 I only created one user account with No password, they all boot directly to the desktop.

Comment: But there is the welcome loading screen